# Is it possible to setup a wireless file server and access the drives from a Windows PC?

Tags: server, file-server

I was hoping to setup a wireless file server using a Raspberry Pi connected to a USB flash drive or hard drive and map to the drive from a Windows PC on the network.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes it's possible, search for samba after you set up the wireless

Answer (score 2):

In theory, any GNU/Linux derived computer with the appropriate hardware can be configured to do what you need. However, you would need to take into account the specifics of the R/P. The main one is that you connect to WiFi using a USB dongle. You also connect the hard disk using a USB connection. Both these connections go through the R/P's internal USB hub. There are two consequences to this:

1. Speed will not be fantastic. R/Ps use a USB 2.0 connection. This does not have much bandwidth (in theory 480 Mb/s, which translates in practice about 30-33 MByte/s). In addition, you will in essence be sharing what little bandwidth is available between the inbound flux (from the drive) and the outbound (to WiFi).
2. With your scheme, power will be supplied both to the WiFi dongle and to the hard drive from the R/P, through USB. All this -and the R/P's own power consumption- must go into the R/P through its own USB port (the smaller one). This is a lot of power, too much in fact for what the R/P can handle.

I have squashed a R/P using an external hard drive over USB, without even speaking of adding WiFi. It lacked enough power to boot.

On the other hand, I have also squashed a R/P just with a WiFi dongle (and no hard drive): power consumption of some WiFi dongles may be quite high, since after all they are radio emitters.

The most simple solution I can think of would be to connect the R/P to a USB hub, one that has its own independent power supply. Then connect the WiFi and hard drive off that. As mentioned before, speeds will not be stellar, but at least it should work.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

What you want to setup is a NAS (Network Attached Storage) that is accesible for Windows machines. So the server you want to install and run is `samba`. See [elinux](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_NAS) for more insight.